# Type alias AAGUID is missing since version 3.1.x

Tags: typescript

I noticed that in the latest TypeScript Version 3.1.x the type alias for AAGUID is missing.

[Search here for AAGUID](https://fossies.org/diffs/TypeScript/3.0.3_vs_3.1.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts-diff.html)

Is it completely unsupported or can we find this elsewhere?

Comment: It was just an alias for type `string`.